I can’t log into my KDE desktop over the login screen in Debian, after deleting some packages
I can’t log into my KDE-Desktop on my Debian 12.6 after deleting some KDE-specific packages.
The login screen appears, but nothing happens when I enter my password.
I was trying to delete some packages to make the system leaner.
What should I do?

Switch to a console (tty)
Press Ctrl + Alt + F2 (or another function key between F2 and F6) to switch to a text console.
switch from the graphical user interface to console 1, also known as TTY1 (Teletype 1)
Execute commands:
updates package lists
sudo apt update
reinstalls kde plasma desktop
sudo apt install --reinstall kde-plasma-desktop
fixes broken dependencies
sudo apt install -f
restarts the system
sudo reboot
If no system-specific data has been deleted or damaged, you should be able to log in normally again.
Will my settings be overwritten if I do this?
No, your personal settings should not be overwritten in /home/USER.
Reinstalling kde plasma only affects system files, not your user-specific settings stored in your home directory.
Be cautious with configuration files for system applications, especially in /etc, they maybe overwritten if no prompt appears.
If you asked about configuration files during reinstallation, you can usually keep your existing ones.
You should always do a backup of your important configuration files and data.
How do I migrate my KDE settings?
